# Javascript regex remove everything after .extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following sample URL which I need to sanitize

```
http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0447522591096_647x329.jpg" border="0" params="">
```

into

```
http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0447522591096_647x329.jpg
```

My question is, which regex should I use to flexibly remove everything after the .extension, regardless of whether its .jpg, or .png or .jpeg?

Also the texts and symbols after the extension will all be different.

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a partial html tag. If its all images just use `replace(/".*/,'')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(.*?(?:jpg|png|jpeg))|.*
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/47

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var s = 'http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0447522591096_647x329.jpg" border="0" params="">';
var r = s.replace(/^(.+?\.(png|jpe?g)).*$/i, '$1');
//=> http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0447522591096_647x329.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to regex would be to just use basic string parsing.

```
var fullUrl = 'http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0447522591096_647x329.jpg" border="0" params="">';
var baseUrl = fullUrl.split(' ')[0];
```

Edit: you may also want to decode the url so you don't get tripped up by % encoding.

```
var fullUrl = 'http://image.s5a.com/is/image/saks/0447522591096_647x329.jpg" border="0" params="">';
var fullUrl = decodeURI(fullUrl);
var baseUrl = fullUrl.split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to do things like this yourself. All languages have libraries for reading HTML, and they're more reliable than doing it yourself. If this is client-side javascript, you could use jQuery; then, if `element` is a jquery object representing the HTML element, `element.attr('src')` will be the value of the `src` attribute.

Comment: Might be helpful to provide a piece of working sample code to exemplify